# PHPSpreadhseet: Not getting output while export data from my database even not a single error?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I changed my code from **PHPexcel to PHPSpreadsheet**, every data is dynamic and coming from Mysql but my few data is **not exporting** even i am **not getting any error** and Data is showing while i **print_r($name[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij6n7.png))** the variable,
Any help or suggestions is appreciated -

Here is my Converted code -

```
    $inn_table = "";     

for($i=0;$i<count($labels);$i++) {

        if($result['qualification']['dd1']!="") {

            for($j=0;$j<count($dd1);$j++) {
                $temp = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);    


                if($temp[0]==$labels[$i]) {
                    $name = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($name[1]);
                     $inn_table .= '<td>'.$name[1].'</td>'; 
                }
            }
        }

         echo $inn_table;
```

**Print_r output** -

Yes
    Category A
    Others
    TAS
    6

How can I **export it in excel with help of PHPSpreadheet**

simple example -

[Check labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij6n7.png)

It checks with labels as you can see in my code and put data in the same label column cell as you can see in picture like if it matched with media type the it's print in media type row as you can see in picture

Comment: Welcome to SO. The exact code for exporting data heavily depends on desired result. It's hard to guess what exactly you need and what have you already tried. [Docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are rather big and have some examples.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin my excel sheet header is already defines so this code check the data with label as you can see `$temp[0]==$labels[i]` and as when data match with header it put it in the same header column i just need to export that data into excel

Comment: Can you post all code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i updated my code Please check once.

Comment: @ama22211 why you use table ? you can set any row with data from db

Comment: Can u elaborate or give example?

Comment: @ama22211 I still don't see any use of PHPSpreadsheet. Even excel sheet header(exel does not have a header, not really) is certainly not defined.  Spreadsheet is a powerful tool, that has its uses. There are a ton of examples for using it, and pretty good documentation on it. That's the best I can do at this point.

Comment: Update: it's highly unlikely that someone will write an generating Excel from scratch, but there is always hope.

Answer (score 0):

That's a example you can edit (in this example i use composer for install PHPSpreadheet):

```
require 'DB.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx as xlsx; // Instead PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing as drawing; // Instead PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory as io_factory; // Instead PHPExcel_IOFactory


$query = 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ?';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$objPHPExcel    =   new Spreadsheet();


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//NAME WORKSHEET
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Test");


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setOrientation(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPaperSize(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A12', 'ROW1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B12', 'ROW2');

$rowCount   =   1;

}
while($row  =   $result->fetch_assoc()){


      //BORDER  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);


      //VALUE
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['row1']);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['row2']);


    $rowCount++; //ADD COUNT 
}

$objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=EXAMPLE.xlsx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Db information and relative query is only example, ***remember to prepare stmt***

Comment: Thanks for help @Simone but as i have already dynamic row header which is from different table and print successfully only need to print dynamic columns after matching with header  according to header row .

Comment: In the part of _//VALUE_ you can see how set value for row(not header), for example  `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['row1']);` will print value of _row1_ start to second cell